# Ignore other DLL Files when debugging DLL Project with target application (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: debugging, dll, visual-studio-2019, access-violation

I have a C++ DLL project in Visual Studio I've downloaded, which is a plugin module for another existing program (a media Player). The DLL created by this project is saved into the addon folder, is loaded by the media player and works great with no issues. However, I would like to be able to step through the code in the library while the player is running to understand how the code works.

The problem is that when I setup the project to launch the media player and step through the DLL project code, it starts fine and I can set breakpoints. But at certain times, the Visual Studio debugger tries to access other loaded DLLs inside the media player, which I don't have source code for, and it crashes the whole thing with an "access violation writing location blah blah blah" error. I have no interest in trying to access any other libraries the program is loading other than the one I have the source code for, so is there any way to prevent the Visual Studio Debugger from trying to hook into these other libraries? I know the error is not due to anything in the DLL project itself because it runs absolutely fine if I just tell it to "Start Without Debugging."

Answer (score 1):

> I have the source code for, so is there any way to prevent the Visual
> Studio Debugger from trying to hook into these other libraries?

Please try these steps:

**Suggestion**

**1)** check **Enable Just My Code** under Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->General

**2)** enter Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->Symbols-->choose **All modules, unless excluded** and then click **Specify excluded modules**

[image]

then input the name of the dlls you want to exclude. Their symbols will not be loaded when you debug your application.

[image]

**3)** do not forget to uncheck option **Warn if no user code on launch(managed only)** under Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->General

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I had all of those options set, and also included the symbol server for the few dlls I'm able to load symbols for from the media player. But as I step through the code, if I even try to step over a section of code that accesses an external dll I can't debug, it still crashes with the same error. Is there anyway to totally skip over the code, or even attach the debugger at a later point in the code after the trouble spots?

Comment: Sorry for that wrong guidance. First, you should set all the exclude dlls which you do not want to debug in the `Specify excluded modules`(the first link) and then input the extra dlls in it. Also, if you want to debug some dlls, you should set their symbol files(.pdb files)  on the Symbol. If the dlls you do not want to debug into, you should exclude their pdb files from the symbol. Also, did you input that dll in the exclude modules?